# Find variance of a given distribution

Tags: probability

$X \sim \exp(\beta)$ and $Y|X = x \sim N(0,x/2)$. How do I find the $\text{E}(Y)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$?

---

$\text{E}(Y)=\text{E}(\text{E}(Y|X))$ which ought to be $0$.

And $\text{Var}(Y)=\text{E}(\text{Var}(Y|X))+\text{Var}(\text{E}(Y|X))$ which should be $\text{E}((X/2)^2)+\text{Var}(0)$. Meaning that $\text{Var}(Y)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\beta^2$?

How would this change if $Y|X$ was distributed uniformly?

Comment: Looks good. By "distributed uniformly", you mean $Y|X = x \sim U(0, x/2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's what's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)},$$
where in this case we have $f_{X}(x) = \beta \exp\left( -\beta x\right), f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{x}\right)$ as the p.d.f.'s of the respective distributions. From this we get the joint distribution function
$$f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\exp\left(-\beta x - \frac{y^2}{x}\right).$$
Now, to get $\mathrm{E}(Y)$, we need $f_Y(y)$, the marginal distribution for $Y$, which we obtain by integrating the joint distribution over the domain of $x$:
$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\exp\left(-\beta x - \frac{y^2}{x}\right) \mathrm{dx}.$$
Also note that $\mathrm{E}(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_Y(y) \ \mathrm{dy}$, so
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(Y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta y}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\exp\left(-\beta x - \frac{y^2}{x}\right) \mathrm{dx \ dy}\\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}} \exp(-\beta x) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty y \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{x}\right) \mathrm{dy}\right) \mathrm{dx}\\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}} \exp(-\beta x) \left[ -\frac{1}{2}x \exp\left( -\frac{y^2}{x}\right)\right]_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} \ \mathrm{dx}\\
     &= 0.
\end{align}$$
Similarly for $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$, using $\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2f_Y(y) \ \mathrm{dy} - \left( E(Y)\right)^2$,
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(Y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta y^2}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\exp\left(-\beta x - \frac{y^2}{x}\right) \mathrm{dx \ dy}\\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}} \exp(-\beta x) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{x}\right) \mathrm{dy}\right) \mathrm{dx}\\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}} \exp(-\beta x) \left( \mathrm{Var}(Y|X)\sqrt{2\pi \mathrm{Var}(Y|X)}\right) \mathrm{dx}\\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\pi x}} \exp(-\beta x) \left( \frac{x\sqrt{\pi x}}{2}\right) \mathrm{dx}\\
     &= \mathrm{E}(X/2)\\
     &= \frac{1}{2}\beta.
\end{align}$$
To see how this would differ for a different distribution of $Y|X$, this is simply a task of recalculating using the new p.d.f. I'm not sure what you meant exactly by $Y|X$ being 'distributed uniformly', I would guess either $U(0, x/2)$ or $U(-x/2, x/2)$.

Comment: I did mean ~U(0,x/2)